# Avoiding exceptions by short circuiting

Tags: java, exception, short-circuiting

The following code is bug free. But, it fine so long as `if (i == a.length - 1 || a[i] != a[i + 1])` condition maintains its order. Swapping the if conditions to `if(a[i] != a[i + 1] || i == a.length - 1)` would throw an exception. Is preventing an exception by short circuiting, an expectable coding standard Or is there some theory / design pattern warning against such coding practices ? If so please advise with links / materials.

```
 public static void eliminateDuplicate(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == a.length - 1 || a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
            System.out.println("now what : " + a[i]);
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding error conditions is the primary reason short circuiting exists.

Comment: Preventing exceptions with short circuiting is done by everybody I've talked to and I've seen it in practically every book. It must be an accepted practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common practice to use short-circuit operator to avoid exceptions. And it is obviously standard.

### [JLS Section 15.24 - Conditional OR operator:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but
>   evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand
>   operand is false.
>
> - ConditionalOrExpression:
>
>   - ConditionalAndExpression
>   - ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression

Given your case, it would be pretty more clear if you use [Conditional && operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) and change your condition to:

```
if (i < a.length - 1 && a[i] != a[i + 1])
```

The intention is more clear in this code on the first look. Frankly speaking I had to go through twice over your condition to figure out what is it doing.

Again not related to concrete question, I'll modify your for loop to use maximum index one less than you are using currently, to avoid the conditional operator entirely:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
        System.out.println("now what : " + a[i]);
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

---

### Some Common Examples:

Some quite common examples where you would see the use of conditional operators to avoid exceptions are:

Overriding `equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof MyClass && ((MyClass)obj).num == this.num;
}
```

Handling `null` reference in some method invocation:

```
// Although there are better way to do this.
if (str != null && str.equals(str2)) {
    // some code
}
```

Avoiding division by zero:

```
if (x != 0 && 4/x > 1) {
    // some code
}
```

Contrary to this, all the above codes will throw exception at runtime, if you use [Boolean Logical Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), and the first expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks - but intention for code was to deal with cases like [1 2 3 4 4], the last 4 needs to be captured, not lost.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper. Yeah sorry, I missed that part. I mean to say, you can avoid conditional, in `if` block.